# What is the best way to make two instances in Solr which use identical schemas?

Tags: mysql, solr, indexing, jetty, multicore

I got indexed a Mysql database using Solr and everything is perfect. Now i got another database which uses exactly the same schema as my first database but with different data in it.

What i want is to use Solr to index also the second database using the same solr schema that i created for my first database since are completely the same!

I read that Solr cores allows you to run multiple instances that use different configuration sets and indexes, but in my case i got the same exactly configuration, the only thing that changes is the database name.

My question is what is the best way two create two Solr instances that use the same configuration?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use two cores and share a schema. Just read the [Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin). But in practice you might want to keep the flexibility and just copy the schema for a second core.

Comment: That's exactly what i want to skip. To duplicate config files , because i am planning to use more than two same schema instances. Anyway your arguments are lofical and i will accept them. I just wondering if there is another way. Cheers!

Comment: If you want to use same config for a lot of cores then read the Wiki I linked.

Answer (score 1):

How about using only one solr instance but have a field in the schema that contains a value which indicates which db/source the record came from.